# how can i use ffmpeg in yii

Tags: video, ffmpeg, wamp, yii, thumbnails

i want to make thumbnails of videos and convert the videos to flv or mp4.
i m using windows7 64bit, wamp, yii 1.1.7

i want to make the thumbnails when the files is uploaded and store them in the thumb dir to be used later

any help, suggestion or alternative

Comment: What have you already tried that just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar with yii and LAMP. I used the Yii uploadify extension to upload the files. Once upload is completed, I move the file to my desired location in the controller. The PHP controller execs an ffmpeg process to find the duration of the file. It then generates the thumbnail from the middle of the duration with an ffmpeg command. Lastly, I create the ts segmented stream with segmenter and ffmpeg commands to support iOS streaming. All these can be automated.

Comment: i have got the compiled version of ffmpeg from a friend and i used the controller to execute the ffmpeg commands and got the thumbnails, thanks

Comment: tommy ,do you have some demo of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a minimum to run ffmpeg commands:

```
    public function execFFmpegCommand($command)
  {
    $sCommand = CEnvConfig::$FFmpegPath." ".$command;
    $buffer = CCommon::runExternal($sCommand);

    return $buffer;
  }



  public static function runExternal($cmd)
  {
    $cmd = "{$cmd} 2>&1";
    exec($cmd, $buffer);
    $buffer = implode("\r\n", $buffer);

    return $buffer;
  }
```

To get stills (thumbnails) from video you need to use FFMPlayer:

```
            $sCommand = $videoFileURI." -ss ".$pointerTimeCode." -frames ".$frames." -vo jpeg:quality=100:optimize=0:smooth=0:noprogressive:nobaseline";

or

            $sCommand = $videoFileURI." -ss ".$pointerTimeCode." -frames ".$frames." -vo png:z=0";

  public function execMPlayerCommand($command)
  {
    $sCommand = CEnvConfig::$MPlayerPath." -nosound ".$command;
    $buffer = CCommon::runExternal($sCommand);

    return $buffer;
  }
```

Comment: Great code! But... Seems like Yii cannot find or evaluate CEnvConfig. Nor can I find it in the docs. Did this change recently?